# Including non-minified Backbone and Underscore in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, backbone.js, underscore.js, minify, wordpress-3.5

I have been trying to debug an intermittent problem in the Wordpress-3.5 uploader, where it seemed a Backbone.js model was getting messed up somewhere. I downloaded the non-minified Backbone.js and Underscore files, pasted them over Wordpress' built-in wp-includes `.min.js` files, but then it gives a different error than usual.

Is this caused by using a slightly newer .js file from the Backbone and Underscore sites? (I couldn't find the exact version Wordpress uses there), or is there a problem with replacing the `.min.js` file with the full file? The script was sent to browser, but would not run the same as the builtins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use **same version** of Backbone/Underscore files when trying to debug.

Just replace a minified js with a normal js shouldn't be a problem.

You can download Backbone 0.9.2 and Underscore 1.4.1 from below urls:

1. https://raw.github.com/documentcloud/backbone/0.9.2/backbone.js
2. https://raw.github.com/documentcloud/underscore/1.4.1/underscore.js

Comment: Where can I find the non-minified versions of Underscore 1.4.1 and Backbone 0.9.2? Is there a proper way to include them rather than overwriting Wordpress' .min.js files?

Comment: @NoBugs see the urls in above answer.